# Printing HTML Input Value to Console on Click

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a code like this:

```
@page
@model AddClassPage
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add Class";
}

<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-dark text-white">
    <h2 class="display-4">Add Class</h2>
</div>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="teacherIdInput">Class ID (number only):</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="0" id="classID" placeholder="Class ID">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="teacherNameInput">Class Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="classNameID" placeholder="Class Name">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-grey">Add</button>
</form>

<script>
   form.addEventListener('submit', function(){
      console.log(input.value);
   });
</script>
```

My goal is to print the Input value to the console when I click the `btn btn-grey` `class` button. But I just couldn't. Could you help? I'll save it to Microsoft SQL after testing if the data comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use `event` object to access `input` elements on `target` property. The `id` that you specified on inputs will indicate which `input` to access on `target` object.

Additionally you can also preventDefault behaviour of form submission using `e.preventDefault()`

```js
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.classID.value);
  console.log(e.target.classNameID.value);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I will ask one more thing. In another file, I put methods such as writing and deleting the database in a class called Database. How can I access these methods? I will save the data I get from the inputs to MSSQL.

Comment: These methods are they JS Code or what ?

Comment: No, I'm connecting to a database with C#.

Comment: Sorry, but this I may not have an answer to as that is not my expertise.